# Join a whole table as single row

Tags: mysql, join

Let's say I have 2 tables like this:

```
--------+-------          
| id    | name |
--------+-------
| 1     | Paul |
| 2     | Jack |
| 3     | Joe  |
--------+-------


--------+--------
| id    | Color |
--------+--------
| 1     | Blue  |
| 2     | Red   |
| 3     | Pink  |
--------+--------
```

I would like to have a result like this:

```
--------+-----------------
| Paul  | Blue,Red,Pink  |
--------+-----------------
```

I don't know if it depends on a complex query or a "simple" keyword that I might have missed. I've searched near the JOIN thing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM main WHERE name = Paul CROSS JOIN colors WHERE 1;
```

But it doesn't seems that easy and it's of course not working.

Any hints or keyword to search for would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Cross Join` and `group_concat`.

**Query**

```
select t1.name,group_concat(distinct t2.color separator ',') as color
from tbl1 t1,tbl2 t2
where t1.name = 'Paul'
group by t1.name;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2183c/5)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function is what you're looking for. Try something like this:

```
SELECT table_names.name, GROUP_CONCAT(table_colors.color) AS color 
FROM table_names 
LEFT JOIN table_colors ON table_names.id = table_colors.id
```

Comment: It wasn't working as expected as it is, but thank you for providing the GROUP_CONCAT() I was missing.